# Как в angular ui-router создавать и обрабатывать пути с несколькими параметрами?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

В приложении возможны состояния:

```
/routes
/routes?filter=someValue
/routes?anotherFilter=anotherValue
/routes?filter=someValue&anotherFilter=anotherValue
```

Как генерировать такие пути и как их потом перехватывать?

Comment: у сервиса `$location` есть свойство `search`

Comment: Это если один параметр. А если больше? Можно конечно сделать JSON.stringify(), но мне кажется это не очень правильно.

Comment: что значит один параметр? там хранится вся строка `?filter=someValue&anotherFilter=anotherValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте сервис `$stateParams`.

```
//app.configure
.state('state1', {
'url': '/routes?filter&anotherFilter'
'controller': 'State1Controller'
}
//controller
myApp.controller('State1Controller', function($stateParams) {
   //$stateParams.filter
   //$stateParams.anotherFilter
});
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters

Answer (score 0):

В документации у [$location есть метод search](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search), который возвращает объект со всеми нужными параметрами роута.
Пример из доков:

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```